# HTML rewrite .htaccess file

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When I used the .htaccess file in to my root folder to rewrite the URL
it occurs error & got this massage   " The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

I am using this rewrite rule in my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule services services.html?
```

http://www.domain.com/services.html to get rewrite url 
http://www.domain.com/services

Please guide me for this

Comment: Your server gives you a massage when there's an error? I'm jealous. :-p

Answer (score 0):

I think its supposed to be

```
RewriteRule ^services$ services.html [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.html
```